# SQL Maintenance Plan - Determining Duration of Steps

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plan

I'm trying to keep a maintenance plan under 30 minutes.  The duration of each step indicates this should be the case, but the plan is running over 1 hour.

The check database integrity ends at 20:04:16 and the next step, update statistics starts at 21:00:30.  What is going on during this gap, and which step is causing the issue?

Maintenance Plan: GP Nightly Full Maintenance
Duration: 01:06:33
Status: Succeeded.

Back Up Database (Full) (ISTAGPSQL1)
Backup Database on Local server connection
Databases that have a compatibility level of 70 (SQL Server version 7.0) will be skipped.
Databases: All user databases
Type: Full
Append existing
Task start: 2020-10-13T20:00:02.
Task end: 2020-10-13T20:01:27.
Success

Check Database Integrity (ISTAGPSQL1)
Check Database integrity on Local server connection
Databases that have a compatibility level of 70 (SQL Server version 7.0) will be skipped.
Databases: All user databases
Include indexes
Physical only
Task start: 2020-10-13T20:01:27.
Task end: 2020-10-13T20:04:16.
Success

Update Statistics (ISTAGPSQL1)
Update Statistics on Local server connection
Databases that have a compatibility level of 70 (SQL Server version 7.0) will be skipped.
Databases: All user databases
Object: Tables and views
All existing statistics
Task start: 2020-10-13T21:00:30.
Task end: 2020-10-13T21:06:32.
Success

Clean Up History (ISTAGPSQL1)
Cleanup history on Local server connection
History type: Backup,Job,Maintenance Plan
Age: Older than 4 Weeks
Task start: 2020-10-13T21:06:33.
Task end: 2020-10-13T21:06:35.
Success

Maintenance Cleanup Task (ISTAGPSQL1)
Maintenance Cleanup on Local server connection
Cleanup Database Backup files
Age: Older than 4 Weeks
Task start: 2020-10-13T21:06:35.
Task end: 2020-10-13T21:06:35.
Success

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if you've already checked this - but given that the 'Update statistics' component starts at a few seconds after 9:00pm, my guess is that you have sub-plans that are on different schedules e.g., the first sub-plan starts at 8:00pm while the second sub-plan starts at 9:00pm. Try looking in the SQL Server agent to review when they're scheduled.

Comment: Just one plan - no subplans.  Thanks for replying SeanB

Comment: Does the stats update always start at 9:00pm, regardless of how long the integrity check takes?